# ASP.NET Core Returning

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I am using Microsoft Northwind example database. I scaffolded the database and everything works besides this code below

I want to make work this logic:

```
select * from Products
join Suppliers
   on Products.customer_id = Suppliers.customer_id
where Products.customer_id = 1
```

My way I tried to make this SQL query in LINQ (No errors in VS 2019):

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
         var test = await (from ep in _context.Products
                 join e in _context.Suppliers on ep.SupplierId equals e.SupplierId
                 where (e.SupplierId == 1)
                 select new
                 {ep.ProductName,e.CompanyName}).ToListAsync();
    }
    return View(test);
```

ERROR after starting the project and going to the Index:

**InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.String]]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DbFirst.Models.Northwind.Products]'.**

Just in case, I am saying that this code works well but it's not what I need:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var test = await _context.Products.Where(x => x.SupplierId == 1).ToListAsync();

    return View(test);
}
```

Comment: Read the error message. It says that your view's `@model` directive specifies one type (`IEnumerable<Products>`) but you're passing a List of anonymous objects to the `View()` method.

Comment: Side note: using a sequence (or list, collection, etc.) as a view's model type is a bad practice. Tutorials use this pattern to avoid creating classes (I assume) but it doesn't scale up. In practice, you'll often end up having to pass more than just one thing to the view and you have to create a container for it anyway. Instead, keep it consistent and create a model class for each view (e.g. `IndexViewModel`) from the start, and organize them in subfolders (e.g. `Models\HomeModels` for `HomeController` models) similar to how views are organized.

Comment: Create a simple class with two string properties called `ProductName` and `CompanyName` and call it `MyModel` -- set the model for your view to be `MyModel` -- and then change `new` clause in your linq statement to `select new MyModel {ep.ProductName,e.CompanyName}`.  The result will be that you are no longer using an anonymous class and the model has only the column values you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David is correct.Your View receives `IEnumerable<Product>` while your action return the list of anonymous type.

You could create a specific ViewModel for your View:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public string ProductName{ get; set; }
    public string CompanyName{ get; set; }
}
```

Then,modify action code to return `List<ProductViewModel>`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
     var test = await (from ep in _context.Products
             join e in _context.Suppliers on ep.SupplierId equals e.SupplierId
             where (e.SupplierId == 1)

             select new ProductViewModel
             {  
                ep.ProductName,
                e.CompanyName
             }).ToListAsync();
}
return View(test);
```

Finally,modify `@model` of Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I added  ProductName and  CompanyName  before ep.ProductName and  e.CompanyName then it worked!

I have another question, how you would add multiple models to one view? Or I need to make new stuff into ModelView to be more professional?